# why Broadcast Receiver Don't work for service application android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a project which is only a service and it has no activity and user interface. I want to start my application background service when phone boot completely. but I never receive the "BOOT_COMPLETED" Message from OS. these are my code:

**Manifest:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.droid.arghaman.location_tracker">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <receiver android:name=".BootBroadcastReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"
    android:label="StartServiceAtBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
    </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
</application>

<service android:name=".mySevice"></service>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

**Broadcast Receiver:**

```
public class BootBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("boot Received", intent.getAction());
        Intent serviceLuncher = new Intent(context, myService.class);
        context.startService(serviceLuncher);
    }
}
```

**myService:**

```
public class LocationNotifierService extends Service {
   Timer timer ;
   @Nullable
   @Override
   public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
       return null;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(){
       timer = new Timer();
       timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
       @Override
       public void run() {

 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Location",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }
          },3000);
      }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){

    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flagId, int startId){
        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

but I never get "boot Received" log.
is there any mistake and is there any way to debug my program?

I Recommend that my project must have only this Service and it cannot have any UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I never receive the "BOOT_COMPLETED" Message from OS

Partly, that is because you do not have a `<receiver>` set up to receive `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcasts.

Partly, that is because your app will not receive broadcasts until something on the device uses an explicit `Intent` to start one of your components. The way your app is set up — without an activity that the user can run — it is unlikely that any app will do this, and so your code will never run.

Also, please bear in mind that Android O has changes designed specifically to prevent background services from running for very long and to limit your ability to get background location updates (which your `location_tracker` name suggests that you want to add in the future). You may wish to reconsider whether writing this app the way that you are is a wise course.

Comment: please provide a solution... how can i start my service without user interaction???

Comment: @Navid_pdp11: There is no solution in general. Android is set up to prevent malware authors from doing what you are trying to do: hide from the user and spy on them.

Comment: you mean there is no way to start service on boot_complete?

Comment: @Navid_pdp11: Sure. Have an activity. When the user launches that activity, your app will then become eligible to receive broadcasts. Until then, it will not.

Comment: i create an activity and open it but still my broadcast receiver not working.... i am only opening my activity and do not call any other function

Comment: @Navid_pdp11: You also need to change your `<receiver>` to listen for `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Intents/OnBoot).

Answer (score 0):

try this in your manifest

```
 <receiver android:name=".BootBroadcastReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"
    android:label="StartServiceAtBootReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
       </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: ... probably want to remove this line `android:exported="false"` - it needs to be exported, which is implicitly the case by default with static receivers with intent filters?